# How To Create Auto Delete Queue In Rabbitmq Using Sockjs-Stomp

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp, sockjs

i am not able to create auto delete queue through sockjs it create durable queue but not delete the queue after a few minute if it is not used. this feature available in rabbitmq 
but not supported in sockjs.

Please suggest me how to create auto delete queue through sockjs

Comment: there is a solution for Rabbitmq look at this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018814/websockets-sockjs-stomp-spring-rabbitmq-delete-user-specific-queues-automat/25342115#25342115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do this by creating an 'auto-delete' policy for queue names matching a given pattern.

I'm using Java/Spring/RabbitMQ in the backend and SockJS/Stomp in the client. All queues rabbitmq creates follow the same  naming convention : suggestions-user*  so once you declare the policy in Rabbit all queues will be deleted after the expiry parameter [Check it out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7lrz.png)

Enable Visualiser plugin if you want to define the policy through UI otherwise you can also do it via rabbitmqctl command in a terminal.