# Stompjs subscribe auto-delete queue

Tags: java, rabbitmq, stomp

When applying the following:

```
client.subscribe(`/user/queue/${ chatRoomId }.private.messages`, callback, {
    'auto-delete': 'true'
});
```

I get the following error:

> 2022-01-10 02:09:31.908 ERROR 99494 --- [ent-scheduler-3]
> o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Received ERROR
> {message=[precondition_failed], content-type=[text/plain],
> version=[1.0,1.1,1.2], content-length=[223]} session=system text/plain
> payload=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'auto_delete' for queue
> 'room-post-6cf8fa...(truncated)

I use RabbitMq vs 3.7: https://github.com/quangthe/docker-rabbitmq-stomp

I'm not sure why it mentions auto_delete as the header to use is auto-delete.
It works well when I omit the header (or use auto_delete which is useless becuase it's ignored), but this will create an infinite number of queues.
Every time a user refreshes the browser, it's not supposed to create a new queue obviously.
Nobody is going to delete thousands of queues manually.

I have a Java backend using the latest dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-stomp</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by using an exchange as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018814/websockets-sockjs-stomp-spring-rabbitmq-delete-user-specific-queues-automat).

Doesn't make a lot of sense to use the most common example using regular queues if they are not auto-delete. Nobody wants to deal with thousands of queues that don't get cleaned up.